# How to install VC++ 2005 Redistributable x64 and x86 silently with WIX

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, vcredist

I'm editing a Setup Project of WIX (Windows Installer XML), and would like to install VC++ Redistributables (2005x86, 2005x64) silently with WIX.
I'm using custom actions in my code shown below:

```
<Product ...>
  <CustomAction Id="vcredist2005x64" ExeCommand="/q" Execute="deferred"
   Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no">
  <CustomAction Id="vcredist2005x86" ExeCommand="/q" Execute="deferred"
   Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no">
</Product>
...
<Fragment>
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="vcredist2005x64" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action="vcredist2005x86" After="vcredist2005x64">NOT Installed</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

When executing the installer generated from the code above, however, a Windows Installer dialog pops up and says: "Another program is being installed. Please wait until that installation is complete, and then try installing this software again."
It seems that the two Redistributables are conflicting (Note that when executing, for example, 2013x64 and 2005x64, no conflicts occur and they are installed silently).

Then I switched to use a Bootstrapper Project (Burn) and wrote the code below:

```
<Bundle ...>
  <Chain>
    <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x64" SourceFile="C:\path\to\vcredist_x64.exe"/>
    <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x86" SourceFile="C:\path\to\vcredist_x86.exe"/>
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
...
<Fragment>
  <PackageGroup Id="vcredist">
    <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x64"
                Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
                SourceFile="C:\path\to\vcredist_x64.exe"
                InstallCommand="/q"
                SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"
                Protocol="burn"
                />
    <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x86" ... />  <!-- same as above -->
  </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

With Burn, no conflicts occur but it's not possible to install them **silently**, i.e., after launching the Bootstrapper, Microsoft Software License Terms dialogs appear. I would like to prevent the dialogs from popping up.
Welcome any advices. Thank you.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, but according to the msiexec docs the switch for silent install is '/qn' maybe replace your InstallCommand with "/qn" istead of "/q"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is almost working as you asked: it is **unattended**, so no license inquiry but it's not fully **silent**, so you will briefly see popups when installing VS2005 dependencies. May be further enhanced but switches seems to be no properly respected.

Anyway, first uncompress `vcredist_x86.exe` (or x64) with 7-Zip or other software to retrieve the internal `VCREDI~3.EXE`. Delete the original and rename the latter to `vcredist_x86.exe` (or x64). After use this WiX bundle:

```
  <Bundle>

    <!-- ... -->

    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x86" SourceFile="D:\vcredist_x86.exe"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="vcredist">
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist2005x86"
                  Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
                  SourceFile="D:\vcredist_x86.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/Q /C:&quot;msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn&quot;"
                  SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"
                  Protocol="burn"
                />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/02/07/update-regarding-silent-install-of-the-vc-8-0-runtime-vcredist-packages.aspx) helped me.

Comment: Your solution works as I desired. This is what I have wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Those redistributables are MSI-based installs. Windows does not allow recursive MSI operations, so you get the error when you install them because another install is aklready running - yours that you're calling the custom actions from.

So this really comes down to a Burn issue, and that should be working, so that's the direction to go in, sorry I can't help with that part.